# Google BigQuery: UNNEST array of structs and unnested item as struct

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a question regarding `UNNEST`ing an Array-column with structs.

My source table schema looks like this

```
fields:
 - id:                                  STRING::NULLABLE
 - response_choices:                    RECORD::REPEATED
 - response_choices.response_option_id: STRING::NULLABLE
 - response_choices.position:           INT64::NULLABLE
 - response_choices.rendered_position:  INT64::NULLABLE
 - response_choices.responded_at:       DATETIME::NULLABLE
```

When I executing the following query

```sql
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(response_choices),
  STRUCT(
    ro.response_option_id AS response_option_id,
    ro.position AS position,
    ro.rendered_position AS rendered_position,
    ro.response_datetime AS responded_at
  ) AS response_choice
FROM my_responses_table,
  UNNEST(response_choices) AS ro
```

The query returns data that includes both the struct (as defined above) but it also adds the columns for the struct flat to the results. So the schema looks like the following

```yaml
fields:
  - id:                                  STRING::NULLABLE
  - response_option_id:                  STRING::NULLABLE
  - position:                            INT64::NULLABLE
  - rendered_position:                   INT64::NULLABLE
  - responded_at:                        DATETIME::NULLABLE
  - response_choice:                     RECORD::NULLABLE
  - response_choice.response_option_id:  STRING::NULLABLE
  - response_choice.position:            INT64::NULLABLE
  - response_choice.rendered_position:   INT64::NULLABLE
  - response_choice.responded_at:        DATETIME::NULLABLE
```

However I'd UNNEST the array in a way that it only adds one field with the struct in it. The reason is that some of the fields in struct conflict with fields that are already in the table source.

I’d like to get something like the following

```yaml
fields:
  - id:                                  STRING::NULLABLE
  - response_choice:                     RECORD::NULLABLE
  - response_choice.response_option_id:  STRING::NULLABLE
  - response_choice.position:            INT64::NULLABLE
  - response_choice.rendered_position:   INT64::NULLABLE
  - response_choice.responded_at:        DATETIME::NULLABLE
```

Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: i think something wrong with the schema (for source table) you presented on the top of your question - please double check and correct if needed

Comment: thanks for the hint, I updated the schema

Comment: makes sense now  - see the answer :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select t.* except(response_choices), 
  response_choice
from `project.dataset.my_responses_table` t,
unnest(response_choices) response_choice
```